# Microsoft Graph API: How to get predefined values list for attributes like preferredLanguage, usageLocation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to consume Microsoft Graph API to provision/de-provision users and groups to/from Azure Active Directory. When I am creating a new user I need to pass values for the attributes preferredLanguage, usageLocation etc. They seem to accept predefined values. I did some google research but did not find any info on how to get these predefined values list.

**What I have Tried:**
Apart from my google research, I tried to read the metadata from Microsoft Graph API(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata), it gives the values for some ENUM type attributes, but not for these attributes. In the metadata returned, the type of these attributes is mentioned as "Edm.String". But they don't accept any random string.

I found an archived page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx, where Culture Names, Codes etc are mentioned, but it seems to be very old.

**My question is:** where can I get these predefined values list. Can i get them from "Microsoft Graph API" itself, if so what is the URI?. Please guide me.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data should be mostly available through the Microsoft Graph Documentation.

For example, looking at the [User Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user):

> **preferredLanguage**
>
> The preferred language for the user. Should follow ISO 639-1 Code; for
>   example "en-US".

> **usageLocation**
>
> A two letter country code (ISO standard 3166). Required for users that will be assigned licenses due to legal requirement to check for availability of services in countries. Examples include: "US", "JP", and "GB". Not nullable. Supports $filter.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It definitely helps. Thank you soooo much Shawn for the very quick response. I'll follow your instructions.